# string slicing in python (meaning of [0:-1])

Tags: python, string, syntax, slice

I have been referring to a few sources of information on slicing strings ([here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-slicing-in-python/), for example).

I wanted to understand the behavior of slicing so I tried the following script.

```
s= 'abc'

print(s[0:1])

print(s[0:-5])

print(s[0:-1])
```

The source I linked above gave me the following

```
arr[start:stop]         # items start through stop-1
arr[start:]             # items start through the rest of the array
arr[:stop]              # items from the beginning through stop-1
arr[:]                  # a copy of the whole array
arr[start:stop:step]    # start through not past stop, by step
```

So, based on the syntax above, I would have thought `print(s[0:1])` would result in `'a'` but the rest  `(print(s[0:-5]) and print(s[0:-1])` would result in `''`

To my surprise, they resulted in `''` and `'ab'`.

So I ran the following code:

```
print(s[0:-4])
print(s[0:-3])
print(s[0:-2])
```

They printed `''`,`''`, and `'a'`, respectively.

I am confused as to how the syntax is working.

P.S. My goal is to set up the slicing such that if the 2nd number ([1st:2nd]) is less than the 1st number, the output is `''`.

Comment: The link you show explains pretty clearly what the negative numbers are doing.  What is surprising about the result?

Comment: @Chris  my apologies. I missed the whole section in the source page about the negative indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative numbers effectively count from the right. So:-

```
s[0:-1]
```

-:means "every element except the last one in s"

Hence:-

```
s[0:-5]
```

-:means "every element except the last five in s"

Since there are not five elements in s, this returns the empty string.

Another example:-

```
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
s[8:-3]
```

-:this is effectively saying "All of the letters in the alphabet except the first eight and the last three".

Comment: my apologies. I missed the whole section in the source page about the negative indexing